# Export each number from string

Tags: javascript

I have a dateTime string like below :

```
 "1396-12-22 12:33:42"
```

How can i export each date number to single int like below:

```
1396
12
22
```

Comment: `str.split(/-/).map(parseFloat)`, if format is always the same.

Comment: As a single int? In your example I can see three ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var res = new Date("1396-12-22 12:33:42")
console.log(res.getFullYear());   // 1396
console.log(res.getMonth() + 1);  // 12
console.log(res.getDate());       // 22

console.log(res.getHours());      // 12
console.log(res.getMinutes());    // 33
console.log(res.getSeconds());    // 42
```

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote. That's discouraging without knowing the reason.

Comment: It's a bit overkill to build a `Date` instance just to parse a string. It's better to use `String` methods or regex. Also, parsing dates from ISO 8601 strings is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: @PedroCastilho, I agree. However, there are advantages of it too for different user scenarios when user don't have to remember the index for the resultant array from regex.

Comment: the voting patterns on the answers to this question are all fd up lol, it's like opposite mode. but it's a poorly defined question as you can see by all the ways people interpreted it, so that's the risk you run answering something like this

Comment: @aw04, yes true that. I believe, even some silly questions make us use think from different perspectives. So I used `Date()` which is overkill; I agree. I would appreciate those who downvoted to reconsider. Thanks :D

Comment: Oh I think your solution is fine, I didn't downvote. But some people interpreted it as only returning the first three numbers and some interpreted it as all the numbers which may have something to do with the downvotes

Comment: Thank you for sharing your perspective :) I will try answering better next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (if using ES6) to do this:

```
let dateTimeString = "1396-12-22 12:33:42"
let dateString = dateTimeString.split(' ')[0];
let [ year, month, day ] = dateString.split('-');
```

If using ES5, the code is instead:

```
var dateTimeString = "1396-12-22 12:33:42"
var dateArray = dateTimeString.split(' ')[0].split('-');
var year = dateArray[0];
var month = dateArray[1];
var day = dateArray[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression:

```
"1396-12-22 12:33:42".split(/\D+/)
```

Gives:

```
["1396", "12", "22", "12", "33", "42"]
```

Comment: OP states he wants 1396, 12, 22 - this returns too many numbers

Comment: also this doesn't return integers

Comment: You are both right. This is a brute force extraction of numbers. My preference goes to @Devendra Lattu as it keeps the date meaning.

Comment: @levif, I appreciate it. Your solution uses simple to understand regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dateTimeString = "1396-12-22 12:33:42";

const dateNumbers = dateTimeString
    .substring(0, dateTimeString.indexOf(" "))
    .split("-")
    .map(value => parseInt(value));

console.log(dateNumbers);
```